# Python: How to find HostName with IP using specific DNS server?

Tags: python, dns, ip

*Context:*

I have **50000+** **ip** addresses of internal network computers from firewall policies.
I am trying to **get the hostname** of all of these, **using** a **specific DNS server**.

*The problem is:*

I don't want to use the main DNS server of the company to avoid crashing it and shutting down production. So I want to specify which one to use.

*What I've tried:*

I have tried dns.resolver, socket.gethostbyaddr and a couple more but it does not seem to work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) There is no guarantee you have PTR records to map IP addresses back to hostnames. 2) if your DNS server crashes because of 50000 requests, that is a problem and it may make more soon to try to solve this 3) "I have tried... but it does not seem to work". You will need to show more code to prove what you are trying. Python `dns` module is completely capable to do what you need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can call **nslookup** as a **subprocess** and then specify the DNS server to be queried using this function. You can put dns='YourDefaultDNSServer' in the function variables to use a DNS server by default if none is specified.

```py
    def reverseLookupDNS(ip, dns='X.X.X.X'):
       a=subprocess.run(['nslookup',ip,dns],capture_output=True, text=True, 
       shell=True)
       if a.stderr:
           return None
       else:
           sortie=a.stdout
           reponse=str(sortie).split(':')
           host = reponse[3].strip(' ').split('\n')[0]
           return host
```

then

```py
    reverseLookupDNS('192.168.1.10')
```

to use the default server specified in the function arguments

or

```py
    reverseLookupDNS('192.168.1.10', "aDNSServer")
```